# Keep selected multiple dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have multiple select dropdown which contains country list.
The requirement is like every customer have different country list. So, I need to store countries list for each customer. So, I have created separate table for selected country list for related customer.
The problem is I need to check whether the country is already there in database or not. If it's there then keep selected that name. o.w. uncheck checkbox.

Multiple select drop down looks like this:

[image]

CODE:

```
<select title="Basic example" multiple="multiple" name="example-basic" size="5">
    <?php foreach($countries as $country){ ?>
        <option value="<?=$country['country_id']?>"><?=$country['short_name']?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Right now, Albania and Algeria is there in that database table. How can I make it checked.
Because I have 2 different tables for country list and selected country list.

Thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't demonstrate you tried anything.

Comment: I tried with array_combine function. But, it needs to have two same size array. I don't know how to check selected values..

Comment: What plugin are you using? In standard HTML, you only need to add `selected` as an attribute to the `<option>` tag.

Comment: multiple select dropdown, but plugin is not the issue here.. "http://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget"

Comment: If this is a database question, you need to share some information about table structure and sql queries.

Comment: jQuery or JS doesn't matter. Read stored country list for user as array, Then, when rendering select (as in your code), check if given country is in array of user countries and add the `selected` attribute to the option if so.

Comment: There will be two different arrays for that. right? How can I loop 2 arrays in single for loop?

Comment: Quit asking us about arrays if you're not going to show us what's in them. Right now, we don't have enough information to help you any more than we already have.